# AWS RDS storage-full

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, storage, rds

For some reason, mysql instance on RDS was storage-full, I tried to truncating one of the table used for logging, there were about 9 million data source in this tables, unfortunately, this sql sentence "truncate tableA;" already run over 60 hours! it was still running and this table seemed to be locked, because when I checked the count of this table, it stuck, is there any other way to leave some spaces for mysql, shall me wait until this truncate sentence completed?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried dropping the table and recreating it? i think that should be quicker than a truncate